# setting permissions on redux actions

Tags: authentication, reactjs, permissions, redux

I am creating a web redux-react app which will have a number of different permission levels. Many users may be interacting with one one piece of data but some may have limitations on what they can do.

To me, the obvious way to set permissions on interactions on the data (held behind the app server) would be to associate certain permissions with different redux actions. Then, when a user saves their state the client side app would bundle up the users action history and send it back to the server. These actions could then be applied to the data in the server and permissions could be checked, action by action, against a user jwt.

This would mean lots our reducer code could be used isomorphically on the server.

I cannot find any resources/disscussions on this. What is the normal way of handling complex permissions in a redux app? Having auth purely at the endpoint seems cumbersome , this would require rewriting a ton of new code that is already written in client side reducers. Is the any reason not to go ahead and create a reducer which checks auth on each action?

Points:

- We must assume actions sent to the server are authenticated, but sent by users that do not have permission dispatch these actions
- If the permissions have been checked and are inside the actions then the reducer can check permissions and be pure

Comment: Most importantly, you need to disallow the actions on the back-end, right? Otherwise, no matter what you do on the front-end, your app will not be secure. After that, in order to guide the user as to what can and cannot be done, you just have to hide/disable your UI elements. Is there really any need to control the actions?

Comment: exactly, the question is, on the backend, after the user has been authenticated and their permissions double checked, what is the best way to decide whether the actions are allowed. Store middleware? In the reducers?

Comment: What are you running on the backend? Node + Redux??

Comment: Yes, node. In my proposed use case we would use redux also (mostly using the some reducers as on the front end). The flow would be: actions are dispatched to reducers on the front end; after a bunch of interaction the user will hit save; the users actions history is sent to the server; the server reapplies the actions to a state on the server, with the permissions attached the the actions having been checked by auth middleware; once complete the state would be persisted to a db..

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the responsibility of action creators to check the permissions but using a reducer and a selector is definitively the way to go. Here is one possible implementation.

The following component requires some ACL checks:

```js
/**
 * Display a user record.
 * 
 * A deletion link is added if the logged user has sufficient permissions to
 * delete the record.
 */
function UserRecord({ username, email, avatar, isGranted, deleteUser }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={avatar} />
      <b>{username}</b>
      {isGranted("DELETE_USER")
        ? <button onClick={deleteUser}>{"Delete"}</button>
        : null
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

We need to connect it to our store to properly hydrate all props:

```js
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    isGranted: (perm) => state.loggedUser.permissions.has(perm),
  }),
  {deleteUser},
  (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
    ...stateProps,
    ...ownProps,
    deleteUser: () => dispatchProps.deleteUser(ownProps.user)
  })
)(UserRecord)
```

- The first argument of `connect` will create `isGranted` for the logged user. This part could be done using `reselect` to improve performance.
- The second argument will bind the actions. Nothing fancy here.
- The third argument will merge all props and will pass them to the wrapped component. `deleteUser` is bound to the current record.

You can now use `UserRecord` without dealing with ACL checks since it will auto-update depending on what is stored in `loggedUser`.

```
<UserRecord user={someUser} />
```

In order to get the above example work you need to store the logged user in Redux's store as `loggedUser`. You don't need check ACL on actions since the UI won't trigger them if current user lacks of permissions. Moreover, ACL have to be checked server-side.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I quite understand. Yes, all the real auth needs to happen server side. I agree that it is the reducers job rather than the action creators job to check my actions. If the user saves, the client sends a big heap of actions to the server, these can then be sent to a reducer on the server. At what point and, how, do we check the actions sent are genuine (ie, action by action, at exactly what point should we make sure the user has the correct permissions to make each action).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an helper function that would be built into actions for checking user rights (locally or remotely) where you would also provide with a callback action creator on error. Of course `redux-thunk` or similar would be needed so you can dispatch actions from other actions.

The key rule you should observe here is:

**Reducers are pure functions**.

Action creators can be **impure**. That means reducers always return the same value given the same arguments. Checking for ACL rights in reducer will violate that rule.

Say let's say you need to fetch the list of contacts. Your action is `REQUEST_CONTACTS`. The action creator would first dispatch something like:

```
// ACL test function
function canAccessContacts(dispatch) {
    if (user !== 'cool') {
        dispatch({type: 'ACCESS_DENIED'});
        return false;
    }
}

// Action creator
function fetchContacts() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        if (!canAccessContacts(dispatch)) {
            return false;
        }

        // your logic for retrieving contacts goes here
        dispatch({
            type: 'RECEIVE_CONTACTS',
            data: your_contacts_data_here
        });
      };
}
```

`RECEIVE_CONTACTS` will be fired once you have data back. Time between `REQUEST_CONTACTS` and `RECEIVE_CONTACTS` (which is likely an async call) is ian opportunity to show your loading indicator.

Of course, this is a very raw example, but it should get you going.

Comment: Is this solution still good if the actions are created client side? I want to attach auth+permissions to actions as they come back to the server then once the actions get to reducer check the permissions..

Comment: @Eoin yes, you can check for permissions asynchronously. Mind that reducers should not be checking for permissions as they are pure functions.

Comment: If the user permissions are attached to the action then the reducers can check permissins and be pure. ie (state, {actionData, badPermision}) => state,  (state, {actionData, goodPermision}) => newState